# How to set specific font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a question.

I link google font(Merriweather) in head tag and write a code down below.

```html
<p class="f1">This is Merriweather font</p>
<p class="f2">This is not exist font</p>
```

```css
.f1 {font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;}
.f2 {font-family: 'erfnwienfniownsdm', serif;}
* {font-family: 'Consolas'}
```

[example link](https://codepen.io/pmx/pen/MWBEaVe)

---

Then first p tag is show text using Merriweather font (correct).

second p tag sets not exist font(erfnwienfniownsdm) so show text using local font.

But I want to use other font(ex. consolas) in second p tag case.

If I write this,

```css
* {font-family: 'Consolas' !important;}
```

then Merriweather didn't work.

I'd greatly appericiate any help!

Comment: So don't add `!important`, and just add `consolas` in your rule for `f2`? Why are you setting a nonsense font for `f2` at all if that's not what you want to have happen?

Comment: I forgot to explain this. Actually .f1, .f2 css is written in a different css file and I can't modify the css file which is written .f2 css. All I can do is add modifications css to other css file.

Comment: So? If you control any CSS at all, you can overwrite `.f2` by simply writing a "more specific CSS rule" because that's what determines which CSS rule wins. If there's an `.f2` in a file you can't modify, just define your own `html body p.f2` and done, that's a _far_ more specific rule and will win over the plain `.f2` rule regardless of load order. Or, if your file is guaranteed to load after whichever file you don't control, then you don't even need that, just declare your own and because it's loaded later it'll also win.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I use ==body * {} == then it worked!